# xargs Format output while cating files

Tags: unix, find, xargs

I am combining xargs with find and have a bunch of files which I want to cat

```
find something
A
B
C
```

Now I am doing

```
find something | xargs cat
```

I want to put Echo the name of the file and some display message between the cat outputs. I tried -t option but it displays all the commands on top. Is xargs the way to go here? If so how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -name something -exec echo "File:" {} \; -exec cat {} \;
```

This is safe even for files whose names contain spaces, newlines, or other difficult characters.

#### Example

Let's have these test files:

```
$ cat A
1
2
$ cat B
3
4
$ cat C
5
6
```

The command output looks like:

```
$ find . -name '[ABC]'  -exec echo "File:" {} \; -exec cat {} \;
File: ./B
3
4
File: ./C
5
6
File: ./A
1
2
```

#### How it works

- `find . -name something`

  This starts the find command with whatever options you like
- `-exec echo "File:" {} \;`

  For every file found, this prints `File:` followed by its name.
- `-exec cat {} \;`

  This prints the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
find something | parallel 'echo {}:; cat {}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `echo` filename and print a message, it might be simpler to use two commands... Use `find` to get the list of files you want to `cat` and then use a `while loop` to `echo` filename and print your message.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' > tmp.txt;
while read f; 
do 
  echo "MY MESSAGE $f"; 
  cat $f; 
done < tmp.txt
```